# How to read number of characters stored in input stream buffer

Tags: c++, io, iostream

I have a quick question - how can I possibly write something in console window to `std::cin` without assigning it to a `string` or `char[]`? And then how to read the number of characters that are stored in buffer?

Let's say that I want to create an array of `char`, but it shall has the size of the input length. I might create a buffer or a variable of big size to store the input and then read its length, allocate memory to my char array and copy it. But let's also say that I am a purist and I don't want any additional (other than stream buffer) memory used. Is there a possibility to access `std::cin` buffer, read the number of characters stored and copy them to my array? I was trying to find the answer for several hours, reading cpp reference but I really couldn't find solution. I couldn't even find if there is a possibility to write something to `std::cin` buffer without assigning it to a variable, aka executing `cin >> variable`. I would appreciate any help, also if you have alternative solutions for this problem.

Also, does somebody know where can I find information about how buffers work (means where computer stores input from keyboard, how it is processed and how iostream works with computer to extract data from this).

Many thanks!

Comment: "write something to std::cin buffer without assigning it to a variable, aka executing cin >> variable" -- do you mean "**read** from std::cin"? That's what your "aka" part does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all in order for the input buffer to be filled you need to do some sort of read operation. The read operation may not necessary put what is read in to a variable. For example, [`cin.peek()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek) may block until the user enters some value and returns the next character that will be read from the buffer without extracting it or you could also use [`cin.get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) along with `cin.putback`.

You can then use the [`streambuf::in_avail`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/in_avail) function to determine how many characters are in the input buffer including a new line character.

With that in mind you could do something like this:

```
char ch;
cin.get(ch);//this will block until some data is entered
cin.putback(ch);//put back the character read in the previous operation
streamsize size=cin.rdbuf()->in_avail();//get the number of character in the buffer available for reading(including spaces and new line)
if(size>0)
{
    char* arr=new char[size];//allocate the size of the array(you might want to add one more space for null terminator character)

   for(streamsize i=0;i<size;i++)
        cin.get(arr[i]);//copy each character, including spaces and newline, from the input buffer to the array

   for(streamsize i=0;i<size;i++)
        cout<<arr[i];//display the result
}
```

That being said, i am sure you have a specific reason for doing this, but i don't think it is a good idea to do I/O like this. If you don't want to estimate the size of the character array you need for input then you can always use a `std::string` and read the input instead.

Comment: Ok. So I copied that code and executed it but no matter what i gave to the input I always have size = 0. And also - why there is not mentioned in the cpp reference that istream::peak() stops when the new line character is brought? After all, there are methods that take input as long as a specific character is not given.

Comment: As you said it returns `eof` when there is nothing to read from the stream and i believe this is the standard behavior. You can try it with `char ch; cin.get(ch); cin.putback(ch);`, this will read the first character from the input and put it back in the stream before you call `in_avail`. I've modified the answer. Both of this approaches work on my platform.

Comment: @zuroslav One more thing, there are also input function that returns(gets) whatever input was given to them like `cin.get()`. So it is likely that `cin.peek()` will not wait for a specific character to be given before returning, it just reads the next character from the input stream,whatever character that may be including new line, without extracting it and returns.